# How to use the pre_option filter before a plugin loads?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

How would I go about overriding an option using the pre_option_ filter before a plugin loads?  I am trying to do something like the below, but I can't do it in the wp_config file, because the add_filter function has not loaded yet, and I can't do it in the functions.php file in my theme because the plugin has already loaded at that point.

```
if (STAGE == 'local') {
    function rlrsssl_options() {
        return array();
    }
    add_filter('pre_option_rlrsssl_options', 'rlrsssl_options');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code that *must* run before plugins are loaded, place it in a [Must Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/). This is just a PHP file placed in `wp-content/mu-plugins/`. Be aware that Must Use Plugins are activated just by existing.